# HTML/CSS current active menu does not show active

Tags: javascript, html, css

please see https://jsfiddle.net/qvh5jsc4/1/

I was thinking job of the

```
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

to reset none active color. But this is not working. Home link stays green.

So how to make the active link shows as green.

I have the following code:

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you include your JS?

Comment: It sounds like you want the selector `li a.active:hover` - https://jsfiddle.net/dx96y3m3/

Comment: @redditor: there is no javascript here.

Comment: @  Josh Crozier: I tested you fiddle , but when I click on other links , they stay black. Can  the active one  turned Green?

Comment: @SNash: For the link that you clicked to become active, you need JS to attach the `active` class. I think you are confusing the `.active` class with the `:active` pseudo-selector (which doesn't need to be added using JS) but the `:active` pseudo applies only when the mouse is down on the link.

Comment: ahh I see. So this is not possible with pure css or html. can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @SNash: You need something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/dx96y3m3/1/). (You need to hover out after clicking on a menu item)

Comment: Or something like https://jsfiddle.net/qvh5jsc4/4/ , with which you do not need to hover out after clicking.

Comment: @Harry Thumbs up for a pure js solution mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using jquery : https://jsfiddle.net/xqyhwq36/3/

```css
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111!important;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #444;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```js
$("ul a").click(function(){
$("ul a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: not working for me. When I click on other links hey stay black.

Comment: if you want to change the color of your links dynamically ( by clicking them ) then you have yo use javascript to assign them a class that gives them color of your choosing. CSS can not change dynamically by it s self

Comment: @SNash: As told in the other comment, it will change unless you use a piece of javascript to add active class to the element that is clicked.

Comment: @ droidbot: this is exactly  what im missing and not sure how to do it. can you please provide a Jfiddle?

Comment: updated my answer to include the javascript that you need

Comment: Just to make it obvious, the code provided in the answer is jQuery and not JavaScript. So, you (OP) would need to include jQuery libraries in your code to make it work. If you want a pure JS version (to avoid other libraries), refer to my fiddle in comments to question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
li a:not(.active):hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

li a.active:hover {
    background-color: #444;
}
```

First the id/class selector then the state selector.

Answer (score 0):

A simple tweak in your CSS should do the trick.

```
li:hover {
    background-color: #111!important;
}
li a.active:hover {
    background-color: #444!important;
}
```